# Is .loc the best way to build a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a fairly large csv file (700mb) which  is assembled as follows:

```
qCode   Date    Value

A_EVENTS    11/17/2014  202901

A_EVENTS    11/4/2014   801

A_EVENTS    11/3/2014   2.02E+14

A_EVENTS    10/17/2014  203901


etc.
```

I am parsing this file to get specific  values, and then using DF.loc to populate a pre-existing DataFrame, i.e. the code:

for line in fileParse:

```
code=line[0]

for point in fields:
    if(point==code[code.find('_')+1:len(code)]):
        date=line[1]
        year,quarter=quarter_map(date)
        value=float(line[2])
        pos=line[0].find('_')
        ticker=line[0][0:pos]

        i=ticker+str(int(float(year)))+str(int(float(quarter)))
        df.loc[i,point]=value

    else:
        pass
```

the question I have is .loc the most efficient way to add values to a existing DataFrame? As this operation seems to take over 10 hours...

fyi fields are the col that are in the DF (values i'm interested in) and the index (i) is a string...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you should never build a dataframe row-by-row. Each time you do this the entire dataframe has to be copied (it's not extended inplace) so you are using n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... + 1, O(n^2), memory (which has to be garbage collected)... which is terrible, hence it's taking hours!

You want to use `read_csv`, and you have a few options:

- read in the entire file in one go (this should be fine with 700mb even with just a few gig of ram).

  ```
  pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
  ```
- read in the csv in chunks and then glue them together (in memory)... tbh I don't think this will actually use less memory than the above, but is often useful if you are doing some munging at this step.

  ```
  pd.concat(pd.read_csv('foo.csv', chunksize=100000))  # not sure what optimum value is for chunksize
  ```
- read the csv in chunks and save them into pytables (rather than in memory), if you have more data than memory (and you've already bought more memory) then use pytables/hdf5!

  ```
  store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
  for df in pd.read_csv('foo.csv', chunksize=100000):
      store.append('df', df)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think it would be much faster to:

1. Import the whole csv into a dataframe using `pandas.read_csv`.
2. Select the rows of interest from the dataframe.
3. Append the rows to your other dataframe using `df.append(other_df)`.

If you provide more information about what criteria you are using in step 2 I can provide code there as well.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options that come to mind

1) Parse the file as you are currently doing, but build a dict intend of appending to your dataframe.  After you're done with that convert that dict to a Dataframe and then use concat() to combine it with the existing Dataframe

2) Bring that csv into pandas using read_csv() and then filter/parse on what you want then do a concat() with the existing dataframe